# I can't find firewall on Windows Server 2003 Enterprise Edition

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server

I Just want to open the 1433 port for SQL Server locally, please I dont know who config this server so when I try netsh firewall , prompt saids "the command not exits" by the way routing and nat are disabled

I cannot find Windows Firewall Option on this Server, thats the most rarely!

Server Version : Windows Server 2003 Enterprise Edition (5.2, Build 3790) without any Service Pack

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2003#Service_Pack_1) the Windows Firewall for Windows Server 2003 was introduced with Service Pack 1. Therefore it is not included in the RTM build which you are running.

After the installation of Service Pack 1 (or better Service Pack 2) you should be able to access the feature.

This [Technet page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778394%28WS.10%29.aspx) describes the changes to the firewall in Service Pack 1 in more detail.

Answer (score 2):

Try opening the Windows Firewall UI from the Start Menu's Run command:

- Start-> Run
- firewall.cpl

You should have the Windows Firewall now.

If the Windows Firewall isn't able to run on your system, consider updating your system to [Windows 2003 Service Pack 2](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=95AC1610-C232-4644-B828-C55EEC605D55&displaylang=en) or better.

Comment: please check the image above

Comment: Thanks to Albic, it appears there IS no Windows Firewall pre-SP1. Of course, it's always recommended to keep up with security fixes. Are you able to apply those service packs?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Control Panel and double-click on Windows Firewall. It will ask you if you want to start ICS, say yes, then you should be able to add the exception there. Don't forget to add exceptions for RDP and www if you use it.

Comment: I cant find Windows Firewall on Control Panel
thanks

Comment: Not sure how, but it sounds like the Windows Firewall has been removed.  Does the Windows Firewall service exist in the service list?

Comment: omg not exists!

Comment: Hm that is no good. Do you have an Anti-Virus program installed? If not, install AVG or something and give it a scan. The firewall is not something that can be easily installed/uninstalled.

Comment: When I begin with this since 2 months ago... MacAffe was installed nowadays the AV is NOD32

Comment: by the way, the main IP is protected by Perimetal Firewall and a Unix Enrouting, so in short terms "is a little secure for us" but I want to try open ports manually how can I achieve this?

Comment: If you can't seem to find the firewall on the server then what leads you to believe the box has firewall rules?  Could it be that SQL server is either not listening on port 1433 or not using TCP/IP as a transport?  Have you tried using localhost:1433?

Comment: Sounds really bad to me...I would consider nuking the server if the firewall is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may not have the Windows Firewall afterall... :)

But your main goal seems to be to enable connectivity to your SQL Server instance. Since I don't know what version/edition of SQL Server you have but I am guessing that you have SQL 2005 as 2008 would not install on Win2003 RTM.
So here is a useful link:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277/en-us